# Is reflection being used when using the 'is' operator in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, reflection

As MVI is getting more and more popular in Android development, the use of Sealed classes increases as well. And we know that we have to determine the actual type of the Sealed class in order to continue with a particular flow from our logic.

So does Kotlin use reflection when using the **'is'** operator for type checks? Tried to go through the documentation, but couldn't find anything about that. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the definition of reflection you’re using. Often “reflection” in the JVM world is used to describe specifically the String-based code meta data inspection from the `java.lang.reflect` package (or Kotlin reflection dependency) that is considered to be inefficient. But a more general definition of “reflection” is any code introspection. `is` arguably fits the second definition, but it is fast/optimized and not part of the first definition.